# How to rename validating peers in IBM Bluemix blockchain: starter developer plan beta

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am planning to do a demo blockchain implementation for asset sharing among my application instances. For that I am using the **Hyperledger Fabric V0.6** service provided in [**IBM Bluemix blockchain**(starter developer plan beta)](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/blockchain?env_id=ibm:yp:au-syd&taxonomyNavigation=apps). 

But in Network tab it is showing the 4 peers as **Validating Peer 0**, **Validating Peer 1**, **Validating Peer 2** and **Validating Peer 3**.

Will it be possible to rename this peers to some name which is closely related to my business to identify them easily?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBM Bluemix Blockchain service based on Hyperledger Fabric v0.6 will soon be removed. Instead, the new Blockchain service(*currently it's vNext Limited Beta, based on Hyperledger Fabric v1.0*) will be officially supported. So, I would recommend you to do the demo based on the new version.

Back to your question, you can not rename the peers. But in vNext, you can customize your `channel` names and also `chaincode` name&version

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
I had started with **Hyperledger Fabric V1.0**, but this **vNext(Limited Beta)** is not available now since it reaches maximum capacity and now the create request is in queue. So I decided to proceed with the **Starter Developer Plan(beta)** for the time being. It would have been better if I can give some names which is related to my business, that's why looking for its possibility.